# Where does maven download the resources if local repository is not set?

Tags: maven-3

I am a maven newbie and am currently trying to set up environment using maven for project developed by a different team. They gave us a settings.xml file and it does not have localrepository entry. I put this file in conf folder of maven installation directory. when I run mvn package, I see message that resources are downloaded but cannot figure out where, I searched for m2 directory and even tried overwriting whatever local reposiorty it was using -Dmaven.repo.local to ~/LearningJava/ but still see that nothing is added to the directories. This is the repo entry in settings.xml
    
                
                
                    rtp-repo
                    rtp-repo
                    http://example.com/artifactory/repo
                    
                        true
                        never
                        fail
                    
                    
                        true
                        fail
                    
                
            
    
When I tried giving the absolute path to -Dmaven.repo.local option, it worked,. But I am trying to see what was happening, where was it downloading stuff when I did not set the local repo in command line and ~/LearningJava?

Comment: `/.m2/repository` in your home directory?

Comment: yep there it was. My bad :(. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, maven will download to ~/.m2/repository -- perhaps look there?